# videojs flash player memory leak in ie8

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer-8, swfobject, video.js

I'm using video.js in an interface where I dynamically create and discard video players but I only show at most 1 player at a time. Ideally I would like to just find a way to clean up the swf video player cleanly rather than refactor a solution that reuses one player.

I'm seeing a memory leak (when the flash player is used) in IE8. After "discarding" each new player the memory used by IE remains constant and after "creating" each new player the memory usage increases. The same implementation in Firefox (using the flash player) does not result in a memory leak so the problem is most likely attributed to IE8.

Before I delete a player/video I set `player.src('')` and I call `player.destroy()` which removes event bindings and triggers, etc.

I also tried using `swfobject.removeSwf()` because it does some extra dismantling to avoid memory leaks in IE (Something to do with setting each function property of the swf object to null).

```
if(player.techName == 'flash'){
     player.src('');
     swfobject.removeSwf(playerID); // some attempt to leverage swfobject
     player.destroy();
     $(player.el).remove();
}
```

The closest thing I can find to someone else having the same problem is:
http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/861-how-to-destroy-a-video-js-object#comment_14896105
and it has gone unanswered.

Any help or leads would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Shame there's no answer to this yet, it's kicking me in the balls right now too - particularly as the latest stable release of video.js consistently crashes IE8, so I'm stuck using the 3.2.0 version.